# How to use angularjs with Sails JS together

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I want to develop Web App using Sails JS and Angular js.
I will use Sails js for Backend and AngularJS for front end.
Please help me.
I was tried to many samples on Google but Most of them are not work Correctly.
So I want really Correct Way to Integrate AngularJS with SailsJS.
Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

That's a little bit sticky things. Nevertheless it's not hard. 
So the main problem is routes. Because sailsJS has routes and angular has it router as also. Here how I did it.

1. I copied contents of **index.html** file to **views/homepage.ejs**.
2. Clean up **views/layout.ejs** file. A left *<%- body %>* only.
3. Copy all the assets - js, css folders to *assets* folder.
4. Make some tricky thing in **config/routes.js**. This setting will allow us to use Angular routes with SailsJS routes. So all the requests that are not starting with */api/* will be considered as an Angular. And all others as a server requests.

`"r|^\/(?!.*api).*|":{
        view: 'homepage',
        skipAssets: true
  }`

5. Since we made changes above. We need to add prefix for server requests. In *config/blueprints.js*.

`prefix: 'api',`

6. Ready to go. Lift your Angular + Sails Application!